# segmentation fault: 11 in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am having trouble finding a segmentation fault in my code, I am new to coding and do not have well trained eyes. Help is greatly appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){

    FILE *input_file;

    int num0 = 0, num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, num4 = 0;
    int num5 = 0, num6 = 0, num7 = 0, num8 = 0, num9 = 0;
    char c;


    input_file=fopen("data.txt", "r");

    while (!feof(input_file)) {

        c = fgetc(input_file);

        if (isdigit(c)) {

            if (c=='0') num0++;
                else if (c=='1') num1++;
                else if (c=='2') num2++;
                else if (c=='3') num3++;
                else if (c=='4') num4++;
                else if (c=='5') num5++;
                else if (c=='6') num6++;
                else if (c=='7') num7++;
                else if (c=='8') num8++;
                else if (c=='9') num9++;
        }

        else if (c=='E'){
            c = fgetc(input_file);
            if (c=='N'){
                c = fgetc(input_file);
                if (c=='D') {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    printf("Number of 0: %d\n", num0);
    printf("Number of 1: %d\n", num1);
    printf("Number of 2: %d\n", num2);
    printf("Number of 3: %d\n", num3);
    printf("Number of 4: %d\n", num4);
    printf("Number of 5: %d\n", num5);
    printf("Number of 6: %d\n", num6);
    printf("Number of 7: %d\n", num7);
    printf("Number of 8: %d\n", num8);
    printf("Number of 9: %d\n", num9);
```

They want me to not have so much code without writing
        fclose(input_file);

```
    }
```

Comment: fclose in the comment above is supposed to be in the code

Comment: There's an edit link under the question.

Comment: Where are you getting the segfault?  You should be able to use `gdb` to trace the fault to the exact line that is breaking your code.

Comment: Learn to use arrays. DRY. Also, only read once per loop.

Comment: How about checking to make sure that file opened? Its a key piece of code in this malaise that actually stands a chance of propagating a NULL pointer because you assumed the file actually opened when in fact it didn't. Assumption is the mother of all.... And closely related, this: `while (!feof(input_file))` [is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Improve your code till you get no warnings. Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the input file exists. If it doesn't, or it is inaccessible, `fopen` returns NULL. Attempting to operate on a NULL file wi crash your program.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reads (`fgetc`) in the loop with single `EOF` check. Some of the reads may attempt reading an ended file, if the previous read reached the EOF.

Comment: This shouldn't matter AFAIK; `fgetc` will just keep returning EOF once you're at the end of the file (so long as you don't close it).

Comment: this shouldn't end with segfault